# Cannot set source on MediaElement driven by clock

Tags: wpf, mediaelement

I have created one simple WPF app.
In my XAML I have:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <MediaElement x:Name="media" Width="200" Height="200" Source="D:\Wpf project\wpfSampleApp\wpfSampleApp\Wildlife.wmv">
        <MediaElement.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MediaElement.Loaded" SourceName="media">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Name= "myBegin">
                        <Storyboard SlipBehavior="Slip">
                            <MediaTimeline Source="{Binding Source,ElementName=media,Mode=OneWay}" Storyboard.TargetName="media"  
         BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:10:59" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </MediaElement.Triggers>                
    </MediaElement>
    <Button x:Name="btnnext" Content="Next" Width="100" Height="30" Click="btnnext_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

and in XAML.cs file, on next button click I must play the next video:

```
media.Source = new Uri(@"D:\\Wpf project\\wpfSampleApp\\wpfSampleApp\\B.wmv");
media.Play();
```

Instead I am facing an error that says "Cannot set source on MediaElement driven by clock."

Please help me to get over this exception, I'd prefer to modify the XAML rather than writing code in XAML.cs file.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's very late to the party, but if anyone needs something similar I found a solution not in an MVVM pattern, but for this case it should be forgivable.

Xaml part

```
<MediaElement Name="Player">
    <MediaElement.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MediaElement.Loaded">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <Storyboard Name="MediaBoard">
                    <MediaTimeline Source="path" Storyboard.TargetName="Player" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </MediaElement.Triggers>
</MediaElement>
```

And CodeBehind

```
private void ChangeLoopedVideo(Uri url)
{
     MediaTimeline timeline = new MediaTimeline(url);
     timeline.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
     Storyboard.SetTarget(timeline, Player);
     MediaBoard.Children.Clear();
     MediaBoard.Children.Add(timeline);
     MediaBoard.Begin();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I met with same issue. Finally got a solution. Here is the solution I implemented.

To Set Source for MediaElement while Clock is assigned to it [using MediaTimeLine] we should first check whether current thread has access to MediaElement. This can be done by boolean values - MediaElement.CheckAccess or MediaElement.Clock.CheckAccess.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says: you cannot set source of `MediaElement` if it is controlled by a clock (i.e. your `MediaTimeline`). You should bind the source of the `MediaTimeline` (only) to an `URI` in your `DataContext`.